# Merge rows from different columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some columns in excel and I need to merge their rows together as the example below:

Current file:

```
column A | column B | column C | column D | column E | column F
001001     Adam          20      001002     Adam       1.2
001001     Brian         21      001002     Brian      1.5
001001     Cameron       25      001002     Cameron    1.1
001001     Daniel        18      001002     Daniel     1.8
001001     Edward        19      001002     Edward     2.3
```

Objective:

```
column A | column B | column C
001001     Adam          20   
001002     Adam          1.2
001001     Brian         21   
001002     Brian         1.5
001001     Cameron       25   
001002     Cameron       1.1
001001     Daniel        18   
001002     Daniel        1.8
001001     Edward        19   
001002     Edward        2.3
```

Is this possible? I'm starting to learn VBA so I'm stuck with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: start the recorder, copy the second group under the first then sort on column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy D:F down below A:C and then sort them seems the simplest solution:

```
  Sub Demo
   Range("D2:F" & range("F2").end(xldown).row).copy Range("A1").End(xldown).Offset(1,0)

 Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=range("b1"),Key2:=range("a1")
  End Sub
```

This assumes that both D and F have no blank cells until the bottom

Comment: Actually, I'm feeling really dumb right now. I solved it just by using the sort option on Excel. But I've tried your answer and it worked too. Thank you!